# Error, but nothing seems to be wrong? cv2 - python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I followed a tutorial line by line on YouTube, and it worked. As this is my first time doing recognition stuff

I haven't changed anything and now it's giving me an error.

```py
import cv2

url = 'http//192.168.1.88:4747/video'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # <----------THIS LINE IS GIVING ME THE ERROR
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.5, 5)

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        print(x,y,w,h)
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 5)

    cv2.imshow('Window', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried deleting the whole code-block and rewriting it but I still get the error. Its like that saying, *only an idiot does the same thing over and over expecting a different result*.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tomas/PycharmProjects/Webcam Phone/venv/Webcam.py", line 9, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Apparently something in `frame` is empty. What do you get if you add `print(ret)` and `print(frame)` before using `cv2.cvtColor(...)`?

Comment: Is the URL still valid? Use cv2.imshow("frame", frame) right after reading the video frame to see if frame grab worked or the video URL is still valid.

Comment: @mkrieger1 and @fmw42 , I'm using my phone as a webcam (as I don't own one). its sending the capture from my phone to whatever goes to the IP address. When I go to the  URL in a browser, it works. but python doesn't work for some reason. I've even imported the time module to add a 'buffer' of some sorts before it displays anything, which I hoped would let it connect. You're correct in saying the `frame` is printing `None`, and `ret` printing `False`. I don't know if it's an issue with the app or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREDIT TO - [mkrieger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) & [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42)  - their comments helped my work out why is was returning nothing.

Missing  `:`  in the URL

Caused the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)` function to not receive any frames from the webcam, so `ret, frame = cap.read()` just returned `False` and `None`

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing what happens when `None` gets passed to `cvtColor()`

You need either test `ret`, or `frame is not None`. If you're using a laptop webcam, it's not uncommon in my experience that it take a few frames for the camera to 'warm up' and return images.